# Why won't my version of bash accept function keyword?

Tags: bash, syntax

My version of bash is:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

If I do the prototype function

```
#!/bin/bash
function f()
{
echo "hello" $1
 }
 f "world"
```

I get `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Why is that?

Output of shopt is:

```
autocd          off
cdable_vars     off
cdspell         off
checkhash       off
checkjobs       off
checkwinsize    on
cmdhist         on
compat31        off
compat32        off
compat40        off
compat41        off
direxpand       off
dirspell        off
dotglob         off
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
extglob         on
extquote        on
failglob        off
force_fignore   on
globstar        off
gnu_errfmt      off
histappend      on
histreedit      off
histverify      off
hostcomplete    off
huponexit       off
interactive_comments    on
lastpipe        off
lithist         off
login_shell     off
mailwarn        off
no_empty_cmd_completion off
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off
nullglob        off
progcomp        on
promptvars      on
restricted_shell    off
shift_verbose   off
sourcepath      on
xpg_echo        off
```

Comment: works for me.. make sure that there are no special, hidden, characters in the file

Comment: How strange. Any tips on how to look for these characters?

Comment: Try `cat -A filename`. It expands control characters to printable forms, and adds a `$` to the end of each line.

Comment: How are you running the file? The error message sounds like it is coming from `ksh` or some other non-bash shell.

Comment: I get that error if I run the script with `dash foo.bash` or `sh foo.bash` (`/bin/sh` is a symlink to `dash` on my system). The `#!/bin/bash` line causes your script to be interpreted by bash -- but only if you invoke it directly, not if you feed it to some other shell.

Comment: @KeithThompson you've nailed it! Just tested the two...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your version of `bash` *does* accept the `function` keyword. The problem is that you're not running your script under `bash`.

I get the same error if I run the script with `dash foo.bash` or `sh foo.bash` (`/bin/sh` is a symlink to `dash` on my system).

`dash` doesn't recognize the `function` syntax.

The `#!/bin/bash` line causes your script to be interpreted by bash -- but only if you invoke it directly, not if you feed it to some other shell.

Rather than invoking a shell and passing your script name to it as an argument:

```
sh foo.bash
```

just invoke your script directly:

```
foo.bash (or ./foo.bash)
```